# Counterexample for Sard's Theorem Replacing "Smooth" with "Differentiable"

Tags: differential-geometry

Is there a differentiable (but not continuously differentiable) function f between Euclidean spaces (or manifolds, whatever) such that the set of critical values of f has nonzero measure?

Comment: Would such a thing even be considered differentiable? You could build a piecewise function that is not differentiable anywhere on some set and then differentiable on the complement of said set

Comment: I guess this is a dumb question when looking up Sard's theorem, but why isn't the zero map a counterexample?

Comment: @avid19 the set of critical value of the zero function is one point: zero. Critical value is the value of the function at a critical point.

Comment: related http://mathoverflow.net/questions/167323/everywhere-differentiable-function-that-is-nowhere-monotonic

Comment: @user126154 oh. Thank you. :)

Comment: @TylerHG I agree with you that it's pretty hard to imagine such a function being differentiable, but this seems like the kind of thing that could pop up in a book like Counterexamples in Analysis.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2391429. There is no such $f$