# A question about a proof that the set of critical values of a differentiable real function defined on the real line is of measure 0

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I asked earlier [Does there exist a real everywhere differentiable function with the set of critical values of non zero measure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2391429/471377)

I found the same question on Mathoverflow with the following proof that the set of critical values is always of measure 0:

Sergei Ivanov (https://mathoverflow.net/users/4354/sergei-ivanov), Counterexample to Sard Theorem for a not-C1 map, URL (version: 2012-11-20): https://mathoverflow.net/q/114000

citing the answer:

"

No, such functions do not exist. More precisely, let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be an arbitrary function, $\Sigma$ is the set of $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $f'(x)$ exists and equals 0. Then $f(\Sigma)$ has measure 0.

By countable subadditivity of measure, we may assume that the domain of $f$ is $[0,1]$ rather that $\mathbb R$. Fix an $\varepsilon>0$. For every $x\in\Sigma$ there exists a subinterval $I_x\ni x$ of $[0,1]$ such that $f(5I_x)$ is contained in an interval $J_x$ with  $m(J_x)<\varepsilon m(I_x)$. Here $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure and $5I_x$ the interval 5 times longer than $I_x$ with the same midpoint. Now by Vitali Covering Lemma there exists a countable collection $\{x_i\}$ such that the intervals $I_{x_i}$ are disjoint and the intervals $5I_{x_i}$ cover $\Sigma$. Since $I_{x_i}$ are disjoint, we have $\sum m(I_{x_i})\le 1$. Therefore $f(\Sigma)$ is covered by intervals $J_{x_i}$ whose total measure is no greater than $\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, it follows that $f(\Sigma)$ has measure 0.

"

Now, I cannot see where one uses in the proof that the function is defined on the real line (as far as I saw, Vitali Covering Lemma is true not only for intervals, but also for balls in higher dimensions).

But it is known that there are functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, $n\geq 2$, which are even continuously differentiable, but which have the set of critical values not of measure 0:

https://mathoverflow.net/a/258145 citing 
H. Whitney, A function not constant on a connected set of its critical points, Duke Math. J. 1 (1935), 514-517.

(cited also by Sard), and

https://mathoverflow.net/a/258147

So why does not the cited proof generalize to functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, $n\geq 2$, and contradict the existence of such examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $C^1$ maps $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, it is not the case that for every $x \in \Sigma$, $\epsilon \geq 0$, there is an open ball $B_x$ containing $x$ and an interval $J_x$ such that $f(B_x) \subset J_x$ and $m(J_x) \leq \epsilon m(B_x)$. All we can guarantee is $m(J_x) \leq \epsilon m(B_x)^{ 1 / n}$.

Comment: as indeed the function $z=x^2+y^2$, which maps the origin centered ball of radius $\epsilon$ to the interval $[0,\epsilon)$, shows.. Thank you.

Comment: ..to the interval $[0,\epsilon^2)$, that is.